# How to add google recaptcha on checkout page

Tags: magento2, google-recaptcha

I want to add google Recaptcha on checkout page in Magento 2.

Please advice me.

Comment: Use this [FREE Plugin](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha/) [GIT](https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_ReCaptcha)

Comment: i have already check but not use for checkout page.

Comment: you add Any forms in Magento, just add configuration options in backend.

Comment: I want to select payment method show google recaptcha @jigar patel